# PostgreSQL backup script not able to access .pgpass

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have created a backup script that I wish to run in a nightly cron job, but whenever I run ./pg_backup.sh I am prompted to provide postgres user password despite that fact that I have a pgpass.config file in place.

This is my pg_backup.config

```
##############################
## POSTGRESQL BACKUP CONFIG ##
##############################

# Optional system user to run backups as.  If the user the script is running as doesn't match this
# the script terminates.  Leave blank to skip check.
BACKUP_USER=

# Optional hostname to adhere to pg_hba policies.  Will default to "localhost" if none specified.
HOSTNAME=

# Optional username to connect to database as.  Will default to "postgres" if none specified.
USERNAME=

# This dir will be created if it doesn't exist.  This must be writable by the user the script is
# running as.
BACKUP_DIR=/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/backups/

# List of strings to match against in database name, separated by space or comma, for which we only
# wish to keep a backup of the schema, not the data. Any database names which contain any of these
# values will be considered candidates. (e.g. "system_log" will match "dev_system_log_2010-01")
SCHEMA_ONLY_LIST=""

# Will produce a custom-format backup if set to "yes"
ENABLE_CUSTOM_BACKUPS=no

# Will produce a gzipped plain-format backup if set to "yes"
ENABLE_PLAIN_BACKUPS=yes

# Will produce gzipped sql file containing the cluster globals, like users and passwords, if set to "yes"
ENABLE_GLOBALS_BACKUPS=no


#### SETTINGS FOR ROTATED BACKUPS ####

# Which day to take the weekly backup from (1-7 = Monday-Sunday)
DAY_OF_WEEK_TO_KEEP=6

# Number of days to keep daily backups
DAYS_TO_KEEP=5

# How many weeks to keep weekly backups
WEEKS_TO_KEEP=1

######################################
```

Note that when I enter the prompted password backup is created as expected. The major problem that I have is that this script won't run in cron job if it needs to prompt for postgres password.
Does anyone know the solution or another work-around about this

Comment: I don't know the script you are using but in general, you need to create a file named .pgpass on the home directory of the user running script. You can read more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-pgpass.html)
Be aware you need to chmod permission to 600 to that file.

Comment: I've done that but still it prompts for password. I've also confirmed that the file is .pgpass and not pgpass.conf

Comment: I am running the script as root so I've placed .pgpass at /root/home directory

Comment: On the line calling the backup function, make sure you **don't** have the `-W` option

Comment: @ JGH which line is this, I honestly can't trace it

Comment: you haven't shown it... typically a line containing `pg_dumpall` or `pg_dump`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is to run the script as a `postgres` user -  a standard user of Postgres database on most Unices:

```
sudo -iu postgres /path/to/pg_backup.sh
```

This user is a authorizes as superuser by default.

Comment: still requests for postgres user password

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is still looking for a solution, here are two options:

a.) just remove the `-h "$HOSTNAME"`

b.) create a .pgpass file and add the flag `-w`, which means:

Never issue a password prompt. If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means such as a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail. This option can be useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to enter a password.